# Retest InApp purchase

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have implemented InApp purchase in my app, and I have set up a test account in iTunes.

But I was only able to test it one time.  Subsequent launches of the app seem to think it was already purchased.  I have tried deleting the App, performing a clean, signing out of iTunes. Nothing seem to work, I think it is because the purchase flag is in the keychain but I am not sure.

So, the question is, how do I re-test my InApp portion of my app?

Thanks for the help

Comment: It's all documented - in short: rckoenes's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Since your test account already bought the item, the InApp purchase server allows the user to restore there purchases.

Thus if you wan't to test the purchasing of the item again you will have to make an new test account.

Comment: That does not appear to work.  I deleted the app, cleaned the build, created a new test account, signed out of iTunes on my iPad, run my App and it still thinks it has been purchased. I have seen many posts where they say this, but it simply does not work... has anyone done it this way?  If so, maybe they can share the steps.

Comment: Weird since the purchases are based on account and not device.

Comment: I agree, but when you delete the app, it does not appear to remove the entry from the keychain.  Before the usage of the keychain, the flag was stored in NSUserDefaults which got removed when the app was deleted.

Comment: Keychain items will stay in the keychain, because you can access the kaychain item from mutiple apps using the same profile. Thus if you want to test it, delete the item form the kaychain with some kind of extra button of setting.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes you could create a consumable product, so you can purchase it multiple times. Your product right now seems to be a non-consumable product, which means that you can only purchase it once per test account.

Comment: This will not work as I want the app to be purchased only once.  Before the usage of the KeyChain, you could simply delete the app and the NSUserDefaults would be deleted and when you purchase it again, iTunes knew you bought it already and did not charge, jet downloaded it again.